# After calling Jquery Val(), Append() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to HTML, JavaScript and Jquery.  I cannot seem to figure out why Append() is no longer appending text to TextArea after I call Val("").  The reason I need to call Val("") because I want to clear out the text in TextArea every time when I start the search.  So on the UI, I would enter text for the name of game or company then I press the button to search for the game based on the input fields.  Below is the code from site.js that I play around with.  Thanks.

```
 var arr = [
    {
        Game:"Double Dragon",
        Developer: "Technos Japan Corp",
        Publisher: "Acclaim",
        Platform: {
            Console: "Nintendo"
        }
    },{
        Game:"Street Fighter 2000",
        Developer: "Capcom",
        Publisher: "Capcom",
        Platform: {
            Console: "Nintendo"
        }   
    },{
        Game:"Super Mario Bros.",
        Developer: "Nintendo",
        Publisher: "Nintendo",
        Platform: {
            Console: "Nintendo"
        }   
    },{
        Game:"Secret Mana",
        Developer: "SquareSoft",
        Publisher: "SquareSoft",
        Platform: {
            Console: "Super Nintendo"
        }   
    },{
        Game:"Final Fight",
        Developer: "Capcom",
        Publisher: "Capcom",
        Platform: {
            Console: "Super Nintendo"
        }   
    },{
        Game:"Super Contra",
        Developer: "Konami",
        Publisher: "Konami",
        Platform: {
            Console: "Nintendo"
        }   
    },{
        Game:"Mega Man",
        Developer: "Capcom",
        Publisher: "Capcom",
        Platform: {
            Console: "Nintendo"
        }   
    }
];


function GameBtnEvent()
{
    //$("#textAreaText").val('');//if I comment this out, Append() call will work, otherwise Append() does not append text to TextArea
    DisplayResults();
}

function DisplayResults()
{
    var found = 0;

    $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
        var gameName = $("#searchTitle").val();
        var companyName = $("#selectionBlock").val();

        if(companyName.toLowerCase() == value.Publisher.toLowerCase())
        {
            $('#textAreaText').append("Title: " + value.Game + "\n");
            $('#textAreaText').append("Company: " + value.Publisher + "\n");
            $('#textAreaText').append("Console: " + value.Platform.Console + "\n\n");
            found = 1;
        }
        else if(companyName.toLowerCase() == value.Publisher.toLowerCase() &&
                 gameName.toLowerCase() == value.game.toLowerCase() )
        {
            $('#textAreaText').append("Title: " + value.Game + "\n");   
            $('#textAreaText').append("Company: " + value.Publisher + "\n");
            $('#textAreaText').append("Console: " + value.Platform.Console + "\n\n");
            found = 1;
        }
    });

    if(found == 0)
    {
        $("#textAreaText").append("game not found");
    }
}
```

Update:
It seems this behavior only occurs on Chrome, but Explorer has no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `#textAreaText` is a `<textarea>` element, then you shouldn't be using `append()` in the first place. Use `val()` in all cases. If you need to append to the existing value, provide a function to `val()` which accepts the current value as an argument which you can use when returning the new value, like this:

```js
function GameBtnEvent() {
  $("#textAreaText").val('');
  DisplayResults();
}

function DisplayResults() {
  $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    if ($("#selectionBlock").val().toLowerCase() == value.Publisher.toLowerCase() || $("#searchTitle").val().toLowerCase() == value.game.toLowerCase()) {
      $('#textAreaText').val(function(i, v) {
          return `${v}Title: ${value.Game}\nCompany: ${value.Publisher}\nConsole: ${value.Platform.Console}\n\n`);
      });
    }
  });

  if (arr.length == 0) {
    $("#textAreaText").val("game not found");
  }
}
```

Also note that I made the logic more succinct as your two conditions were pretty much identical, you just need to make the AND logic in to an OR statement.

Comment: Wow, I'm not the only one who knows how to use the function argument to setters like `.val()`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, however when I use your code, I put alert("hello") inside the function DisplayResults() just to debug why the code is not responding, so the alert does not even pop up.  So I think i might copied it wrong.

Comment: That sounds like you've got an error somewhere. Check the console for details